# Selecting the next (not immediately) input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have three input tags separated by span tags, like this

```
<input class="some-class" type="number" maxlength="4">
<span class="bull">&bull;</span>
<input class="some-class" type="number"maxlength="4">
<span class="bull">&bull;</span>
<input class="some-class" type="number" maxlength="4">
```

How do I select the next input tag using jQuery in order to do something? My jQuery code below does not select the next input tag using `.next()` function

```
$(':input').keyup(function (e) {
    if ($(this).val().length == $(this).attr('maxlength')) {
        $(this).next(':input').focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**jQuery `.next()` method:**](https://api.jquery.com/next/)
>
> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

It's because the `.next()` method returns the **immediately following sibling** element. Since the immediate following sibling is a `span`, nothing is selected.

One option would be to use the [`.nextAll()` method](https://api.jquery.com/nextall/) instead. Then chain [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) in order to select the first match:

```
$(this).nextAll(':input').first().focus();
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/o9ezg7rt/)

```
$(':input').keyup(function (e) {
    if (this.value.length == $(this).attr('maxlength')) {
        $(this).nextAll(':input').first().focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.index()` and `.eq()` methods:

```
var $inputs = $(':input');

$inputs.keyup(function(e) {
    if ( this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength') )
       $inputs.eq( $inputs.index(this) + 1 ).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use the .siblings(), to find the input that sibling to its :

```
$(':input').keyup(function(e){
  if($(this).val().length==$(this).attr('maxlength'))
    $(this).siblings('input').focus();
    // do something
  });
```